# Using SystemParametersInfo from C# (SPI_GETSCREENREADER SPI_SETSCREENREADER)

Tags: c#, user32

Am I doing this correctly?

```
[DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern long SystemParametersInfo(long uAction, int lpvParam, ref bool uParam, int fuWinIni);

...

public static bool IsScreenReaderRunning()
{
    long SPI_GETSCREENREADER = 70L;
    bool bScreenReader = false;
    long retVal;

    retVal = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENREADER, 0, ref bScreenReader, 0);

    //uint iParam = 0;
    //uint iUpdate = 0;
    //bool result = false;
    //bool bReturn = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENREADER, iParam, &bScreenReader, iUpdate);
    return bScreenReader;
}

public static void ScreenReaderOn()
{
    long SPI_GETSCREENREADER = 71L;
    bool bScreenReader = true;
    long retVal;

    retVal = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENREADER, 0, ref bScreenReader, 0);
}

public static void ScreenReaderOff()
{
    long SPI_GETSCREENREADER = 71L;
    bool bScreenReader = false;
    long retVal;

    retVal = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENREADER, 0, ref bScreenReader, 0);
}
```

Comment: Is the above code not working for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pinvoke declaration is completely wrong, it was copied from VB6 code.  The return type and arguments are not long (the VB6 int32 type), they are int.  Pinvoke.net is a decent site to get good declarations.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, int fWinIni);
```

Don't forget to throw Win32Exception when you get a false return so failure isn't silent.

Comment: Hans, thanks very much for the reply. I still cannot get it to work. All I need is a working SPI_GETSCREENREADER method - just a C# method to check for the reader. Do you have a working example? I can't seem to get any variation of it to work from C#. What do I pass in the IntPtr??

Comment: You can lie in the pinvoke declaration and make it "ref int".  You'll get 1 back if a reader is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180958), the last parameter to SystemParametersInfo should be:

```
int SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02;
```

When changing the value.