# How to detect screen reader is running?

Tags: screen, coded-ui-tests, screen-readers

In my case i have to decide whether the screen reader is running or not. And at the same could any body share the information about if the Coded UI is an screen reader or not??
[C# : How to detect if screen reader is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079716/c-sharp-how-to-detect-if-screen-reader-is-running)

This logics is related to my query, but it doesn't works for the coded UI.

Comment: Microsoft has lots of documentation about how Coded UI works via the UIA and MSAA interfaces. What is your question that is not answered by those documents?

Comment: My question is that the coded UI is screen reading tool or else

Comment: Coded UI does lots more than a screen reading tool can do. Did that answer help? What is your real question?

Comment: I have some of the logic to suspect whether the peer is created for System screen reader or any other client tool. I have a doubt regarding this my logic is working for Coded UI or not, If it is not a Screen reader means it doesn,t work

Comment: @AdrianHHH okay. Let we come to end up the discussion. we have override the OnCreateAutomationPeer for implementing the Coded UI. The same OnCreateAutomationPeer is called for Screen reader also(ex. Narrator tool default screen reader tool from windows). Is there any possibility to differentiate the OnCreateAutomationPeer is triggered from screen reader or Coded UI.