# How can I detect if a browser is a screen reader?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, screen-readers

I understand someone asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412919/asp-net-mvc-how-to-detect-if-user-is-using-a-screen-reader) but that was for `ASP.NET` and the answer no longer applies in ASP.NET Core.

How can I find out, in ASP.NET Core, on the server side if the browser is running on a screen reader?

Comment: The correct answer to the linked question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52931224/43846) _"It's not possible to detect whether a user is running a screenreader. If it were possible, it would open a door for unscrupulous types to home in on people with disabilities, or for a totally different "accessible" browser experience to be delivered, rather than building interfaces that are inclusive by design."_

Comment: The answer to the linked question answers this as it has nothing to do with what is running on the server, be it ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core, PHP, or anything else.